# UWP Create App Package fails for release mode

Tags: c#, uwp, .net-native

I am trying to create app package for a UWP app (side loading) in release mode it fails with below error. It works fine for debug mode

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     ILT0021: Could not resolve type
>   'System.Security.SecurityZone'    MyApp.ModuleName

[image]
[image]

Project Properties
[image]

When I enable **Compile with .NET Native tool chain**, I get following error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     ILT0005:
>   'C:\Users\username.nuget\packages\runtime.win10-x86.microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.1.8\tools\x86\ilc\ilc.exe
>   --gatekeeper @"C:\Projects......\obj\x86\Release\ilc\intermediate\gkargs.rsp"'
>   returned exit code 1  MyApp.Module

When I try to do build on Azure DevOps I get this error

> (BuildNativePackage target) ->  2019-02-06T15:14:28.4996296Z
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.1\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(792,5):
>   error : ILT0021: Could not resolve type 'System.Security.SecurityZone'
>   [D:\a\1\s\ProjectFolder\MyApp.ModuleName.csproj]

**Update 02/14/2019**

---

Problem was with bunch of Powershell packages I installed from nuget, I removed it all now I am able to create the package. **But the package fails to pass App Certification Kit test** with the following errors

Windows security features test

> FAILED Binary analyzer Error Found: The binary analyzer test detected
>   the following errors: File C:\Program
>   Files\windowsapps\myapp.module.subver_1.0.21.0_x64__7p23rrj50tgdp\clrcompression.dll
>   has failed the AppContainerCheck check.

**Supported API test**

> FAILED Supported APIs Error Found: The supported APIs test detected
>   the following errors: API sysctl in libc.dll is not supported for this
>   application type. Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions.dll calls this
>   API. API RtlGetVersion in ntdll.dll is not supported for this
>   application type. Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions.dll calls this
>   API. API LoadLibraryExW in kernel32.dll is not supported for this
>   application type. clrcompression.dll calls this API. API
>   RtlCaptureContext in kernel32.dll is not supported for this
>   application type. clrcompression.dll calls this API. API
>   RtlVirtualUnwind in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application
>   type. clrcompression.dll calls this API. API UnhandledExceptionFilter
>   in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   clrcompression.dll calls this API. API ExecuteAssembly in uwphost.dll
>   is not supported for this application type.
>   MyApp.Subver.exe calls this API. API
>   DllGetActivationFactory in uwphost.dll is not supported for this
>   application type. Myapp.subver.exe has an export that
>   forwards to this API.

Comment: It seems that there's no document shows that the `Security.SecurityZone` is supported in UWP. The UWP supports the [.NET Standard 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=netstandard-2.0&term=System.Security.SecurityZone), but I also has not found this in it.